# Success and Error messages showing on different page

Tags: error, forms

Some of my forms submit via AJAX and reload the page on complete. I have the $this->_initLayoutMessages(‘core/session’); line in my controller when the page loads, but the success/error messages never appear on my form page. They appear throughout the rest of the site – the home page, customer account pages, etc. Any ideas on what I’m missing that might allow them to appear on the page itself? I have a call to global messages in the template of the page that I am using as well...

Page is located at /marketplacepolicies/marketplaceaccount/editpolicies/

Here is the controller for the page:

```
    public function editpoliciesAction(){
$this->loadLayout( array('default','marketplacepolicies_marketplaceaccount_editpolicies'));
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Seller Policies'));
            $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

and the form submit action:

```
public function saveAction(){

            $wholedata=$this->getRequest()->getParams();

            if(!(empty($wholedata['info']))){
            $data = json_decode($wholedata['info'], true);

            $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();

            foreach($data as $set){
                if (is_null($set[0])){
                    $policies=Mage::getModel('zerobars_marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies');
                    $policies->setData('policy_title', $set[1]);
                    $policies->setData('policy_details', $set[2]);
                    $policies->setData('partner_id', $partnerid);
                    $policies->save();
                }
                else {
                    $collection=Mage::getModel('zerobars_marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('policy_id',array('eq'=>$set[0]))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('partner_id',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                    if(count($collection)>0){
                        foreach($collection as $c){
                            $c->setData('policy_title', $set[1]);
                            $c->setData('policy_details', $set[2]);
                            $c->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        $this->_getSession()
                ->addSuccess('Your new policies have been saved.');
        $this->_redirectUrl('marketplacepolicies/marketplaceaccount/editpolicies', array('_secure' => true));

        }
    }
```

In response to alex_b - here is what is in my _getsession after I delete a policy:

```
Mage_Customer_Model_Session Object ( [_customer:protected] => [_isCustomerIdChecked:protected] => 1 [_persistentCustomerGroupId:protected] => [_skipSessionIdFlag:protected] => [_data:protected] => Array ( [_session_validator_data] => Array ( [remote_addr] =>  [http_via] => [http_x_forwarded_for] => [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36 ) [session_hosts] => Array ( [dev.zero-bars.com] => 1 ) [messages] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection Object ( [_messages:protected] => Array ( ) [_lastAddedMessage:protected] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Success Object ( [_type:protected] => success [_code:protected] => The policy has been deleted. [_class:protected] => [_method:protected] => [_identifier:protected] => [_isSticky:protected] => ) ) [customer_id] => [customer_group_id] => [id] => 6 [wishlist_display_type] => 0 [display_out_of_stock_products] => 1 [wishlist_item_count] => 0 ) [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1 [_origData:protected] => [_idFieldName:protected] => [_isDeleted:protected] => [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: Show how you add these messages and also show your controller method for page where messages should be shown

Comment: Added code for both

Comment: What do you have in `_getSession`?

Comment: Not sure - how can I tell?

Comment: That method should be implemented in controller class

Comment: So it appears the success messages are going into my session, but just not displaying on the page.

Comment: I mean show implementation of `_getSession`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I'm adding success/error messages to session in Save action. That's really the only place I'm touching that method.

Comment: okay... show ALL your controller...

Comment: Found the problem - I added a call to the messages block in my phtml file and it is working now.  <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following line to my .phtml file and it is working now.

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
```